# Is there a way to run Rcrawler without downloading all the HTMLs?

Tags: r, web-crawler, rcrawler

I'm running Rcrawler on a very large website, so it takes a very long time (3+ days with default page depth). Is there a way to not download all the HTMLs to make the process faster?

I only need the URLs that are stored in the INDEX. 
Or can anyone recommend another way to make Rcrawler run faster?

I have tried running it with a smaller page depth (5), but it is still taking forever.

Comment: Can you provide website link and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same issue. Depending on the source, in some cases I am even running at depth 1.

Best,
Janusz

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but a co-worker suggested using LinkExtractor to only extract URLs without downloading: 

https://rdrr.io/cran/Rcrawler/man/LinkExtractor.html

Let me know if this works for you. Best, Yannick